# Pop navigation controller and select tab?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Hi guys I have a navcontroller inside a tabbar. When I select a button inside the root view controller I push another view controller. In it I take some user input and have a finish button.

My problem is that when the user selects this button I want to go straight to another tab, but at the same time I want to pop to the root view controller in the current tab, so that the next time the user presses the tab he/she will go to its original state. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

after pop the navigation controller call the `setSelectedIndex:` on your tab bar controller instance.

and you can also handle your tab bar controller `delegates` in your app `delegate` -

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

here you can pop your navigation controller to root.